# Python django Need return name instead of id foreginkey

Tags: python, django

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='default name')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.TextField(default='0')
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    keyword = models.OneToOneField(KeyWords, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

model don't return data from ForeignKey

Comment: can you edit your question with more detail?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want the objects in `category` and `keyword` fields. Can you show us your view and serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = Product.objects.get(...)
p.type.name
p.category.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a `__str__` method in your ProductCategory model. This way you will have a descriptive name for each entry into that table. Without it, your entry is best described by the id field.